# How to add access.log to each vhost in apache

Tags: apache2, vhosts

Here is my current vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        UseCanonicalName Off
        VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%0/public
        <Directory /var/www/%0/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
                DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory


</VirtualHost>
```

How can I get a access.log for each %0 vhost?

FYI.. If it matters, this is a debian install.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the TransferLog in your VirtualHost definition. Don't forget to restart your Apache service when changing configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        UseCanonicalName Off
        VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%0/public

        ErrorLog/var/logs/%0/error.log
        TransferLog /var/logs/%0/access.log

        <Directory /var/www/%0/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
                DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Director>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I thought ErrorLog does not allow wildcards, %0?